# Updating CI from 2.1.0 to 2.1.4

Tags: codeigniter

I want to update CodeIgniter from the version 2.1.0 to 2.1.4 and I would like to ask you if deleteing system folder from 2.1.0 and replacing it with 2.1.4 system folder will be enough or I need to make some changes in application folder too?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrading.html

Comment: @Nish there is no direct upgrade from 2.1.0 to 2.1.4

Comment: @twenkistat All you need to do following http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_211.html, because since v2.1.1, just `system` files has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes to be done in total for moving from 2.1.0 to 2.1.4

```
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions CHANGE ip_address ip_address varchar(45) default '0' NOT NULL

This config file has been updated to contain more user mime-types, please copy it to application/config/mimes.php.

Replace the system folder.

Replace index.php file.
```